# Font Awesome: How to make the background-color out of the shape delimitation transparent?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Let's say I have this font-awesome icon:

```
<i class="fa fa-times-circle pull-right fa-2x" style="background-color: white; color: red;" aria-hidden="true"></i><
```

With the body background set to black

```
body {  
  background-color: black;
}
```

I would like the background that delimits the shape to be transparent (so like the body backround black while the inner background within the circle remaining white), is it actually possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/8u39n0sq/

Basically how to avoid the square thing this big white ugly square while the background-color of center of the shape is white?

Comment: So, you mean the blue part to be transparent while the f remains white?

Comment: @Highdef sorry it was the wrong fiddle, just updated my post.

Comment: One absolute alternative would be to upgrade to Font Awesome 5. You could take advantage of its layered icons and just use a circle with a times symbol in it and color both.

Comment: Instead of passing the color directly, you can make use of radial gradiant to color the portion you need and rest could be transparent. I've provided a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using several fa-stack with the inner shape I wanted to use.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg success">
 <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg error">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-times fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Although it defeats the purpose of delimiting the background: http://jsfiddle.net/cLpybq20/

Not exactly the same as the glyphs I was using but it fits my needs and appear less tweak-ish.

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of `radial-gradient(white 50%, transparent 50%)` and tweak it around according to your need. Hope, this helps :)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8u39n0sq/2/

```css
body{
background:black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-times-circle pull-right fa-2x" style="background: radial-gradient(white 50%, transparent 50%); color: red;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a workaround, but you can consider adding an `:after` pseudo element in order to add a white background behind the icon:

```css
body {
  background-color: black !important;
}

i {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

i:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

i:before {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<i class="fa fa-times-circle pull-left fa-2x" ></i>
```

It basically creates a white circular element, and arranges it behind the icon using `z-index`. I used `4px` in `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties in order to make sure the white background doesn't go out of the icon's boundaries.

Comment: Nice alternative but a bit too much work. Either way, its one to deal with it :)

Comment: Would definitely recommend creating a style for this along the lines of `.fa-rounded` or something similar; rather than applying it to `<i>` globally.  Still perhaps the most elegant workaround.

Answer (score 1):

`background-color:transparent` put it on the `span`.

i.e. `<span class="fa-stack fa-lg icon-facebook" style="background-color:transparent">` you can put it in a class if you want.

I've supplied a [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/nfz9sucn/824/).

Comment: That doesn't really answer OPs question.  They want the background color present enough to make the `X` portion of the shape white.

Comment: This isn't the JSfiddle they were referring to, they updated it.